# Пометка checkbox нажатием на строку или на кнопку

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

1. Имеем таблицу, внутри таблицы в одной из ячеек checkbox. Хочется при нажатии на строку активировать/деактивировать его (прям как в phpmyadmin). В инете есть пару решений на эту тему, но к сожалению там нужно добавлять class, который у меня занят. Есть ли альтернативные методы?
2. Можно ли при нажатии на кнопку пометить checkbox? Или несколько таких? (т.е. только пометить, при повторном нажатии, что бы пометки не слетали)

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, у элемента может быть несколько классов, перечисленных через пробел.

Comment: Вы хотите использование чистый javascript или готовы использовать фреймворки (например jquery) ?

Comment: да мне хоть какой ни будь пример. адекватный. дальше я во первых применю, во вторых многому научусь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на jquery то можно так:

```
$('.RowClass').click(
                 function(){
                    $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked","checked");//выделение всех чекбоксов на кликнутом контейнере, снять выделение через removeAttr("checked")

                 });
```

html делаете что то типа:

```
...
<tr class="RowClass"><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td></td></tr>
...
```

так же можно не таблицей а дивом или чем другим. Суть в том что мы вешаемся на элементы с  классом и по клику ищем внутри него чекбоксы...

для того чтобы было снять/поставить - усложните функцию клика - добавьте скажем в $(this).attr("state") - нужное состояние и в зависимости от него снимайте или выставляйте чеки (не забудьте обновить аттрибут state)

Да, именно в текущей реализации будет фича - при клике на чекбокс так же сработает клик и выставит все чек боксы. Думаю придумаете как этого избежать - вариантов масса. Но если не справитесь, обращайтесь, подскажу.

Comment: сделал именно так. хотя с кодом особо и не по фантазировать. ест-но JQ подключил. у меня не сработало. сейчас разбираюсь, в чем же дело

Comment: Опечатался, класс tr естественно <tr class="RowClass" ... а не ".RowClass"

Answer (score 1):

Чекиться и наоборот будет по любому, чтобы сделать реакцию на область заверни чек в лейбл вот что то типа: <label for="check1"><input id="check1" type="checkbox" /></label>

Comment: работает, но если сам input находится внутри label - не работает 8-(